# Using IP as a dynamic DNS for another IP

Tags: networking, ip, dynamic-dns, whitelist

Can I use an IP as dynamic DNS for another IP?

I explain: I normally use http://freedns.afraid.org to have a dynamic DNS updated with my current local IP (which is dynamic); then mine
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX becomes example.mydomain.ext

Since I should connect to a server where access is only allowed for certain IPs, I can not use this methodology because it does not accept domain names but only IP, so I should have to have such a system

XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX becomes YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY

so that I can communicate YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY to the server and be always in whitelist.

Is there some service that allows something like that (even for a fee)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. An IP is not a DNS entry.

You might be able to use a VPN or Proxy - possibly you will have to run them yourself and rent a server for that.